# What's the best way to setup playwright in Apache Airflow in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I've been asked to learn `Docker` so that we can eventually setup our web scraping scripts in `Apache Airflow` Docker + Kubernetes clusters. If I am using these terms the wrong way, it's because I am a beginner at Docker. I do not know a whole bunch, but I will try to explain the details.

`Apache Airflow` do have their own image that I have used so far, but their [explanations](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) indicate that the only way to install `python` packages would be through `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` which I've added as an instruction in my own Dockerfile.
The problem is that for `playwright` to work, it needs to install browsers, and this is where it gets tricky...

To simply run the command `playwright install --with-deps` would be the right way to go, but to install those dependencies, you need `root` previlieges which I don't have...

`playwright install --with-deps` failing:
[image: playwright install --with-deps failing]

Installing everything as `root` does not work either (makes the project WAY more complicated if not impossible). To top it off, running the command prompts you for `root` password, which does not seem to be available at all.

This is the point where I have given up, but I am thinking that MAYBE it's better to use `playwright`'s own image and then build `apache airflow` manually.

Which way would be best to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#example-of-adding-airflow-provider-package-and-apt-package Just change to root user for installing playwright

Comment: If it was that easy, I would probably not ask this question here :)

`E: Unable to locate package libgobject-2.0.so.0` and the same message shows for ALL the other packages. Yes, I did a `apt-get update` before this.

Comment: @W1ck3d were you ever able to resolve this? I have run into this issue as well and have tried everything I can think of to resolve this, but cannot overcome it.

Comment: I have not resolved this issue as I am not longer working on that solution.
However, I think that if the issue still exists in their current version of that Docker image, they should look into it... I imagine there are plenty of people like us ;)

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted an issue on Playwright's Github asking about this question as well: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18284

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is using playwright docker image as base image, then you won't need to install its dependencies. Take a look to the documentation here: https://playwright.dev/docs/docker

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out Playwright is not supported for ARM64, which includes the Apple M1 chip.

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18284

As of the time of this posting, the solution to this problem unfortunately seems to be to use an AMD64/x86 architecture chip as opposed to an ARM chip. The following Dockerfile works on x86 but not ARM, and virtualizing the architecture does not seem to work either.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.2

USER root
RUN apt update 
RUN python3 -m pip install playwright
RUN python3 -m playwright install --with-deps
USER airflow
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to setup playwright in Apache Airflow in Docker is to use a custom Docker image that installs playwright and its dependencies, and then use the PythonOperator or BashOperator to run the playwright scripts.

### Explanation

Playwright is a Python library that allows you to automate web browser actions, such as navigating to a URL, filling forms, clicking buttons, taking screenshots, etc. It supports multiple browsers, such as Chromium, Firefox, and WebKit.

Apache Airflow is a platform that allows you to orchestrate and schedule workflows, such as data pipelines, ETL jobs, machine learning tasks, etc. It has a web interface that lets you monitor and manage your workflows, and a rich set of operators that let you execute different types of tasks.

Docker is a tool that allows you to create and run isolated containers that contain your applications and their dependencies. It makes it easier to deploy and run your applications in different environments, such as development, testing, and production.

To use playwright in Apache Airflow in Docker, you need to do the following steps:

1. Create a custom Docker image that installs playwright and its dependencies, such as Node.js, Python, and the browser binaries. You can use the official playwright image as a base image, or create your own image from scratch. You also need to install the Apache Airflow package and any other packages that you need for your workflows.
2. Create a Dockerfile that defines your custom image. For example, you can use something like this:

```py
# Use the official playwright image as a base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright

# Install Apache Airflow and other packages
RUN pip install apache-airflow

# Copy your Airflow configuration file
COPY airflow.cfg /root/airflow/airflow.cfg

# Copy your DAGs and scripts
COPY dags /root/airflow/dags
COPY scripts /root/airflow/scripts
```

3. Build your custom image using the docker build command. For example, you can use something like this:

```py
docker build -t my-playwright-airflow-image .
```

4. Run your custom image using the docker run command. For example, you can use something like this:

```py
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name my-playwright-airflow-container my-playwright-airflow-image airflow webserver
```

This will start the Airflow webserver on port 8080 of your host machine. You can access the web interface by visiting http://localhost:8080.

5. To run the Airflow scheduler, you can use another docker run command. For example, you can use something like this:

```py
docker run -d --name my-playwright-airflow-scheduler my-playwright-airflow-image airflow scheduler
```

This will start the Airflow scheduler that will trigger your workflows according to your schedule.

6. To run the playwright scripts, you can use the PythonOperator or BashOperator in your DAGs. The PythonOperator allows you to execute a Python function as a task, and the BashOperator allows you to execute a bash command as a task. For example, you can use something like this:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

# Define a Python function that runs a playwright script
def run_playwright_script():
    import playwright.sync_api as p
    with p.sync_playwright() as pw:
        browser = pw.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("https://example.com")
        page.screenshot(path="example.png")
        browser.close()

# Define a DAG that runs the playwright script every day
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="playwright_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
)

# Define a task that runs the playwright script using the PythonOperator
playwright_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="playwright_task",
    python_callable=run_playwright_script,
    dag=dag,
)

# Alternatively, you can define a task that runs the playwright script using the BashOperator
# You need to specify the path to the script and the browser binary
playwright_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="playwright_task",
    bash_command="node /root/airflow/scripts/playwright_script.js --browser=chromium",
    dag=dag,
)
```